# what does Overfull \hbox (95.6542pt two wide) mean?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I don't know what this warning means

```
Overfull \hbox (95.6542pt two wide) in paragraph at lines 94--95
```

I added

```
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
```

from other repost, but the warning still going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that something is 95pt (over 3cm) wider than the space that it is assigned to. So most likely sticks into the right margin by that amount.

The source for the problematic text is on lines 94 to 95 of (one of) your source files.